# Specify the Java memory allocation pool address

Tags: java, java-native-interface, mmap

With the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` Options, it is possible to set the initial and maximum size of the memory allocation pool. Using *strace/truss* on Linux and AIX I found out, the JVM internally uses the (k)mmap system call. The *address*-Parameter is NULL, therefore the operating system decides, at which virtual memory address it maps the memory.

```
$ truss java -Xmx512M Hello 2>&1 | grep mmap
kmmap(0x00000000, 536870912, 3, 17, -1, 0x00000000, 0x00000000) = 0xB0000000
```

Is is possible, to specify this address?

Background: I have to call legacy code via the Java Native Interface (JNI), which requires huge amounts of non-relocateable data (2 GB in a 32 bit address space) mapped at a specific location in memory. This region overlaps with the location of Javas memory allocation pool.

Edit: This is the actual memory layout:

```
0x0... AIX
0x1... Text
0x2... Stack
0x3... Heap
0x4... Heap
...... Legacy Data (2 GB)
0xd... Shared Library Text
0xe... unused
0xf... Shared Library Data
```

My goal is to move the Java memory allocation pool from 0xb/0xc into the 0x3/0x4 segments, which is also available in the standard (non large) memory model.

Comment: Can you edit the legacy code to make its memory location configurable?

Comment: `which requires huge amounts` any estimate in mb or gb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could turn this problem inside-out. Start a native process, and do what you need to do to reserve your non-negotiable space (mmap or whatever). Then use Java's [invocation API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) to create and start a JVM inside your native process. I can't find any documentation about how that JVM does its memory management, but [it stands to reason](http://www.mapping.com/words.html) that it will play nicely with memory that has already been allocated by the host process (i would guess it just uses the local malloc), so it will find somewhere else to put its heap. If you leave the 0x3-0x4 region unallocated, you can hope it will put it there.

However, i think there's a real risk that there just isn't enough address space left in your memory model for a JVM. The 0x3-0x4 region is, what, 512 MB? If you can fit a whole JVM (heap, stack, perm, VM structures, etc) in there, then fine, but if not, you may find that when the JVM can't allocate contiguous memory for the heap, it gets very upset. Or it may not. I really don't know.

So, having suggested this, i would strongly recommend that you don't do it, and instead follow [sleske's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585605/specify-the-java-memory-allocation-pool-address/4585676#4585676) and put the native code in a separate process.

Comment: Using the suggestet Java Invocation API I got a working C++ prototype. In the small memory model, AIX puts stack and heap into the 0x2 segment. The prototype then maps 2 GB beginning at the 0x5 segment. Finally, it creates a JVM and calls the main method, leaving only the 0x3 segment for Java. And yes, I am absolutely aware that this is highly platform specific, non-portable, dangerous and ugly, but it is a first step away from the iron grip of Corba. Yay.

Comment: @Frank: i think it should be reasonably platform-agnostic and portable. No comment on the other adjectives!

Comment: Nifty trick. I had never heard of this "invocation API" (though I had wondered how e.g. Oracle manages to embed a JVM into their DBMS). Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I have never heard of a way to configure the allocation pool address. If there is such a setting, it's probably very obscure.

The only way to be sure is to look at the source of the JDK/JRE, available at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/ . If the `NULL` parameter is hardcoded, you're out of luck.

*For an alternative solution, if you cannot fix the misbehaved native code:*

You could write a small native program to call your native code, then call the program from Java (via `Runtime.exec`). That way the naughty code gets its own OS process with separate addresss space. Of course that's only feasible if there's not too much back-and-forth between native code and Java.

Or make the code into a small server that runs in parallel to your Java app, so the two can communicate...

*Additional note:*

I just noticed in the manpage of `mmap` that giving an address to `mmap` is not necessarily supported:

> MAP_FIXED: Interpret addr exactly.
>   [...]
>   It is implementation-defined whether
>   MAP_FIXED shall be supported.
>   MAP_FIXED shall be supported on
>   XSI-conformant systems. [...] When
>   MAP_FIXED is not set, the
>   implementation uses addr in an
>   implementation-defined manner to
>   arrive at pa.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap

So even if you manage to let the JVM call `mmap` with a certain address, that may still not succeed.

Comment: Thank you for the source code hint. Maybe we have to compile our own Java executable. But I would rather avoid that. I was not able to locate the *right* mmap starting at hotspot/src/os/linux/launcher/java.c

Comment: The legacy code sounds insane. Fork it off its own process so it can do its own insane stuff, with a small wrapper that lets you send requests to it over its standard input, and get responses from its standard output. If you try that and it's not fast enough, communicate with it using shared memory - allocate a direct ByteBuffer on the java side, then use a little bit of JNI to set up the shared mapping. Share that mapping in the legacy code process.

Comment: @Tom: The shared memory trick seems like a good idea; didn't think of that when I proposed putting the code into a process of its own.

Comment: thanks. I'd worry that it would be a bit of a nightmare to work with, though - i'd definitely try streams first!

Answer (score 1):

One idea you can try is to use an LD_PRELOAD to inject your own kmmap behavior. Google provides an example of the LD_PRELOAD to inject a custom malloc in the [TCMalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) project.

Comment: Both, your and Toms ideas sound really good to me. I will try both, when I am back at work in, omg, 8 hours. Writing a (hopefully) sane server is not (yet) possible, I'm afraid. Thanks for the great advice and... good night ;-)

Comment: This sounds like a hackish and dangerous solution. OTOH, this is a dangerous and hackish problem, so, sadly, it's probably appropriate :-/.